# "every two days" and "every second day"

Tags: grammar, phrases

> 1)
>   | day1(o) day2(x) | day3(o) day4(x) | day5(o) day6(x) | day7(o) day8(x) |...
>
> 2)
>   | day1(x) day2(o) | day3(x) day4(o) | day5(x) day6(o) | day7(x) day8(o) |...
>
> 3)
>   | day1(o) day2(x) | day3(x) day4(o) | day5(x) day6(o) | day7(o) day8(x) |...

(o) means the days of doing something or available days. Case 3) means only one day is randomly available within every pair of days in any order.

If there is no additional context, are both able to mean 1) and 2)? Personally the word 'second' makes me feel only 2) is for 'every second day'.
If none have 3), are there any recommendable and short intelligible phrases?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "every other", as given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/every%20other), for example

> I go to the club every other day.

and the "other" does not need to be stated.

Another phrasing is with "alternate", also given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alternate), for example

> I walk to work on alternate days.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your phrases describes case 3 because the boundaries between the pairs of days are artificial. If you do something on day 2 and also on day 3 then you have done it every day for days 2 and 3. If you then leave it until day 6 you have only done it once in days 3, 4 and 5 so you have not done it "every second day" or "every two days" except on average.

If you say you are doing something every two days you either have to do it on every odd numbered day or on every even numbered day, it doesn't matter which but you have to be consistent.

If you say "every second day" then it initially appears that you only do it on even numbered days; but when you start counting those days is arbitrary unless the start time is fixed. So if you say "We are going to clean the deep fat fryers every second day" and your restaurant is open 24/7 then which day you start is up to you.  However if you are at a week long music festival starting on a Saturday and a given band is appearing on every second day you would expect them to appear on Sunday, Tuesday and Friday.